# I'm getting an error: pathspec 'branch-name' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages, next.js

I'm currently deploying a nextJS site to github pages but was getting an error upon running `npm run deploy`. I'm suspecting it is a git checkout error but not sure where to start investigating.

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed. I've used ZEIT Now to deploy my application instead. See:
https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/deploying-a-nextjs-app/deploying-to-zeit-now

Then, assigned my domain name to my ZEIT Now deployment. For my code to still be visible in Github, I've just pushed my NextJS site to the repo.